# Rectangle Symbol in Electrical Diagram

Tags: wiring, symbol

I am checking a Nissan forklift wiring diagram and don't know what the rectangles with one and two diagonals are. I would appreciate any idea about this.

[image]

Comment: they could be resistors of specified power ratings, check if the schematic says anything about it.

Comment: Nissan is known to use the symbol with the single diagonal line for fuses, and their position in the diagram would make that very likely. The ones with two lines might be wiring harness connectors.

Comment: @ GodJihyo. That makes lots of sense to me.

Comment: @ GodJihyo You are right! They are harness connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Rectangle Symbol in Electrical Diagram*

There are various symbols used for fuses and this is one of them: -

[image]

[Image link](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2019/09/fuse-circuit-breaker-symbols.html)

Comment: Awesome! This is very useful.